# django2: url based on pk not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-2.0

I want to have a form (webpage) for the model ImpCalendar so I can edit it's data.
The url should have the calendar_id (primary key), which i set in the urls.py

The model (ImpCalendar) has a ForeignKey to Establishments. I do not use that foreignkey in the view/form so i don't know if it is relevant.

If i do in views.py;

```
return render(request, 'importer/calendaredit.html', {'form': calendar})
```

i do see the data on a page, but not a (edit) form. Just the data, not the fill-in fields.

When i do

```
return render(request, 'importer/calendaredit.html', {'form': form})
```

which sounds logical to me, I get the error

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'calendaredit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['importer\\/calendar\\/(?P<calendar_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

It seems to me, the value returned for the calendar_id is now forms-data (html) which it can not do anything with.  But i don't know what I am doing wrong. It has to do something with the html code and the values being transported to it, but i am last.

models.py

```
class Impcalendar(models.Model):
    establishment = models.ForeignKey(Establishments, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.establishment)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
import datetime
from importer.models import Impcalendar, Establishments

class ImpcalendarForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Impcalendar
            fields = ['id', 'url']
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from importer import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('calendar/<int:calendar_id>/', views.calendaredit,    name='calendaredit')
]
```

views.py

```
def calendaredit(request, calendar_id):
    calendar = get_object_or_404(Impcalendar, pk=calendar_id)

    print (calendar.url)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImpcalendarForm(request.POST, instance=calendar)
        if form.is_valid():
            calendar.save()
    else:
        form = ImpcalendarForm(request.POST or None,  instance=calendar)
    return render(request, 'importer/calendaredit.html', {'form': form})
```

calendaredit.html

```
{% extends 'importer/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ form.id }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'calendaredit' form.id %}" method="post">
   <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.id }}
      {{ form.url }}
   </div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass *both* things, calling them what they are, and reference the calendar not the form.

```
return render(request, 'importer/calendaredit.html', {'form': form, 'calendar': calendar})
```

...

```
<form action="{% url 'calendaredit' calendar.id %}" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks! 2nd time. I owe you :-) logical after all. But i didn't see this in the examples i was comparing my work with. Nice!